# probability generating function with die

Tags: statistics

> Given a fair six-sided die. Find the probability generating functions for the number of the throw on which the rth six appears. Hence find the probability that the fifth six occurs on the 20th throw.

For the rth six is it true that $X~Geo((1/6)^r)$, so PGF is $(1/6)^rt+(1/6)^r\times(1-(1/6)^r)t^2$ etc? And for the 20th throw do I look for the coefficient of $t^{20}$?

Answer (score 1):

We will calculate the PGF as asked for in the problem. The probability that the $r$-th six occurs after $n$ rolls of the die is
$$ \frac{1}{6} \binom{n-1}{r-1} 
\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-r}  \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{r-1}.$$
Therefore the PGF is
$$p(z) = \sum_{n\ge r}  \binom{n-1}{r-1} 
\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-r}  \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^r z^n =
 \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^r  \left(\frac{6}{5}\right)^r
\sum_{n\ge r}  \binom{n-1}{r-1} 
\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n  z^n \\=
\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^r 
\sum_{n\ge r}  \binom{n-1}{r-1} 
\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n  z^n =
\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^r 
\sum_{n\ge 0}  \binom{n+r-1}{r-1} 
\left(\frac{5z}{6}\right)^{n+r} \\= 
\left(\frac{z}{6}\right)^r 
\sum_{n\ge 0}  \binom{n+r-1}{r-1} 
\left(\frac{5z}{6}\right)^n.$$

Now note that $$ \sum_{n\ge 0}  \binom{n+r-1}{r-1} q^n = \frac{1}{(1-q)^r}$$
so that $$ p(z) = \left(\frac{z}{6}\right)^r  \frac{1}{(1-5z/6)^r} =
\left(\frac{z}{6-5z} \right)^r$$

It follows that the desired probability is
$$ [z^{20}]  \left(\frac{z}{6}\right)^5  \frac{1}{(1-5z/6)^5} =
\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^5 [z^{15}] \frac{1}{(1-5z/6)^5} =
\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^5 \binom{15+4}{4}
\left( \frac{5}{6}\right)^{15} \sim
0.0323525. $$

Answer (score 0):

See "negative binomial". With parameters r and p, a negative binomial random variable represents the trial number of the rth success when each trial is independently a success with probability p.

r = 5
p = 1/6
i = 20

(sorry in advance for formatting, coding errors etc.)

$p(i=20)$ = ${19 \choose 4}$$(1/6)^5$$(5/6)^{15} $

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward application of the Negative Binomial Distribution where the number of trials $n$ is fixed and made up of $k$ failures and $r$ successes, the $r$th success occurring on the $n$th trial
$$X \sim NB(k;r,p)=\binom {k+r-1}{r-1}p^r(1-p)^k$$

$k$ is the number of failures within the $n$ trials, the number of times a six was not rolled

$r$ is the number of successes within the $n$ trials, the number of times a six was rolled

$p$ is the probability of success, of rolling a six
$$X \sim NB(15;5,\frac{1}{6})=\binom {19}{4}\bigr(\frac{1}{6}\bigr)^5\bigr(\frac{5}{6}\bigr)^{15}$$

With a little effort, Marko Riedel's answer could be generalised to prove the result I've quoted